# TFS 2012 Team Build Get Solution Configuration

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

We have built a customized TFS build template that builds all the projects in a solution file in their own folders. We have, let's say, two solution-level configurations `SOLConf1` and `SOLConf2` as well as two project-level configurations `PROJConf1` and `PROJConf2`. In the `Build Definition`, I select a .sln solution file and the `SOLConf1` configuration.

Now in the `Configuration Manager` window, when I select `SOLConf1` as the **Active Solution Configuration**, I see 5 projects selected, and they all have the `PROJConf1` configuration. So far so good.

We have modified the project files so that the TFS Team Build output directory is customized:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
   <_PackageTempDir>
      $(TeamBuildOutDir)\$(SolutionName)\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName)            
   </_PackageTempDir>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

I would expect `$(Configuration)` to return the solution-level configuration (i.e. `SOLConf1`), instead, it returns the project-level configuration (i.e. `PROJConf1`). I couldn't find a property from the list of [MSBuild Reserved and Well-Known Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx) that would give the solution-level configuration.  Inside the template, the variable passed in to MSBuild for configuration is called **platformConfiguration.Configuration**, which is the configuration I selected in the build definition (i.e. `SOLConf1`).

Now my question is: is there a way to get this variable using MSBuild macros, such that I will have something like

```
$(TeamBuildOutDir)\$(SolutionName)\$(platformConfiguration.Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName)
```

If not, how would one access the solution-level configuration inside MSBuild using MSBuild macros?

Answer (score 0):

> We have built a customized TFS build template that builds all the
>   projects in a solution file in their own folders.

This is a common issue with many possible solutions.  When I ran into this problem I used the advice on [this blog](http://blog.stangroome.com/2012/05/10/override-the-tfs-team-build-outdir-property-net-4-5/), but with .NET 4.5 this is handled via an MsBuild property.

```
/p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutput=true
```

I really love avoiding having to edit the TFS Build Templates.

Comment: Getting the project name is not an issue. I need to get the solution configuration name.

Comment: But I wasn't showing you how to get the project name, I was showing you an out of box method to force TFS to respect your project outputs.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't give me the solution configuration name, does it?

Comment: No but it invalidates your need to reinvent the wheel, doesn't it?

Comment: You are absolutely right, and have a perfectly valid point. However, this does NOT answer my question.